# How to use append with pickle in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i need to append to a pickle file (as i don't have the entire dictionary with me at one go). So for doing the same I have written the following code:

```
 import pickle
 p={}
 p[1]=2
 q={}
 q['a']=p
 p={}
 p[2]=0
 pickle.dump(q, open("save12.p","ab"))
 f={}
 f['b']=p
 pickle.dump(f,open("save12.p","ab"))
```

However, when I am loading the pickle file I don't find the value of dictionary f there?????

Can someone please suggest as to how should I go about appending in a pickle file???

Also databases like 'dbm' are not working for my need as i am working on windows

Comment: What makes you think that two appended pickle streams will somehow be magically accepted as one new object? If your data is too big to fit into memory, use a database (you have many choices, dbm ins't the only thing out there).

Comment: The [`ZODB`](http://www.zodb.org/) works fine on windows; it stores pickles too.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Pickle streams are entirely self-contained, and so unpickling will unpickle one object at a time.

Therefore, to unpickle multiple streams, you should repeatedly unpickle the file until you get an EOFError:

```
>>> f=open('a.p', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump({1:2}, f)
>>> pickle.dump({3:4}, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
>>> f=open('a.p', 'rb')
>>> pickle.load(f)
{1: 2}
>>> pickle.load(f)
{3: 4}
>>> pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

so your unpickle code might look like

```
import pickle
objs = []
while 1:
    try:
        objs.append(pickle.load(f))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: wow, never knew it was possible to store multiple objects in a pickle

Answer (score 32):

```
#To append to a pickle file
import pickle

p={1:2}
q={3:4}
filename="picklefile"
with open(filename, 'a+') as fp:
    pickle.dump(p,fp)
    pickle.dump(q,fp)


#To load from pickle file
data = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as fr:
    try:
        while True:
            data.append(pickle.load(fr))
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

Comment: Is there no other way than with try?

Comment: This code is flawless,however just an addition.Incase <TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes> is thrown please modify with open(filename, 'a+') as with open(filename, 'ab+')