# Shelves an multiple items

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a quote input that puts multiple quotes inside a file (coupled with the authors name). I have tried with pickle, but I could not get more than 2 pickled items inside a file and finally I decided to use shelf.

However, I am having some trouble with shelves as well.

I dont really know how to put multiple items inside a file, even if I can shelf one.

```
import pickle
import shelve

quote = []
author = []

def givequote():

    f = shelve.open('quotation')
    ## open the shelve so that i can write stuff in it

    f["quote"] = raw_input("What quote has its place in the quote book? \n to quit press Q\n\n")
    ## ask for input so that i can put stuff into quote,  
   ##quote is a random value so its a problem, i might have to make a key/value first.
    if quote != "Q":
        f['author'] = raw_input("what author said that? \n to quit press Q \n\n")
        if author == "Q":
            print "goodbye"
    elif quote == "Q":
        print "goodbye"
    f.close()

def readquote():
    f = shelve.open('quotation')
    print "%3s\n - %s" % (f["quote"], f['author'])
```

thank you.

After finding out how it works I plan to try to make the same program using classes ( was thinking of nested ones) and methods, just to practice figuring out my inner programmer.

Comment: It is required to use `pickle` and `shelve`? Looks fairly simple otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pickle. As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761991/how-to-use-append-with-pickle-in-python) describes, you can append a pickled object to a binary file using open with append in binary mode.

To read the multiple pickled objects out of the file, just call `pickle.load` on the file handle until you get an EOF error.

> so your unpickle code might look like
>
> ```
> import pickle
> objs = []
> while 1:
>   try:
>     objs.append(pickle.load(f))
>   except EOFError:
>     break
> ```