# Writing a variable in a file

Tags: python, printing, hex, dump

I am creating this "hexdump" program, and the problem that I am having is writing in the file because I need it to dump the data in a file instead of keeping it in the terminal.

P.S: I'm a bit new to Python, so my friend helped me in coding this.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import pickle


def hexdump(fname, start, end, width):
    for line in get_lines(fname, int(start), int(end), int(width)):
    nums = ["%02x" % ord(c) for c in line]
    txt = [fixchar(c) for c in line]       
    x = " ".join(nums), "".join(txt)
    y = ' '.join(x)
    print (y)
    f = open('dump.txt', 'w')
    pickle.dump(y, f)
    f.close()


def fixchar(char):    
    from string import printable
    if char not in printable[:-5]:
        return "."
    return char


def get_lines(fname, start, end, width):
    f = open(fname, "rb")
    f.seek(start)
    chunk = f.read(end-start)
    gap = width - (len(chunk) % width)
    chunk += gap * '\000'
    while chunk:
         yield chunk[:width]
         chunk = chunk[width:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        hexdump(*sys.argv[1:5])
    except TypeError:
        hexdump("hexdump.py", 0, 100, 16)
```

I know that it is quite a mess, but I need to print the data in a file.

Comment: p.s: it only writes one line which is the last one :/

Comment: fix the indentation in the `for` loop

Comment: fixed but it still prints one line in my file :(

Comment: nope. you're overwriting the previous content.

Comment: well i think you are right cause it prints only the last line so any suggestions to make it print it all ??

Comment: Open the file outside the for loop

Answer (score 2):

For appending to a file, you need to use 'a' mode rather than 'w' (which overwrites), like so:

```
f = open('dump.txt', 'a')
```

But, in case of pickling, (saving objects into files), you probably want to modify your code according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762056/1256112

```
def hexdump(fname, start, end, width):
    with open('dump.txt', 'ab') as writeable:
        for line in get_lines(fname, int(start), int(end), int(width)):
            nums = ["%02x" % ord(c) for c in line]
            txt = [fixchar(c) for c in line]       
            x = " ".join(nums), "".join(txt)
            y = ' '.join(x)
            print(y)
            pickle.dump(y, writeable)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but i want the output format to be like this :                69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 73 79 73 0d 0a 69 6d 70 6f  (Ascii here)

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks, but at each end of every line it writes "p0" and every line starts with ' .S" ' any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Using this code it worked perfectly:

```
def hexdump(fname, start, end, width):
    with open('dump.txt', 'ab') as writeable:
        for line in get_lines(fname, int(start), int(end), int(width)):
            nums = ["%02x" % ord(c) for c in line]
            txt = [fixchar(c) for c in line]       
            x = " ".join(nums), "".join(txt)
            y = ' '.join(x)
            print(y)
            pickle.dump(y, writeable)
```

Now the problem is that when I open `dump.txt` I find this:

```
S'69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 73 79 73 0d 0a 69 6d 70 6f import sys..impo'
p0
.S'72 74 20 70 69 63 6b 6c 65 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 64 rt pickle......d'
p0
```

so how to get rid of "S'" and "p0"?