# How to save the file with request locally in PC and error handling

Tags: python

Currently I am doing as follow, to getting response and save the file locally in my PC-

```
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != status.HTTP_200_OK:
        raise BadRequestError('message')
    return subprocess.call(['wget', url])
```

But what I want, to save the response In my PC when `response = requests.get(url)` with error handling, instead of doing `subprocess.call(['wget', url])` again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import requests
import pickle

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')

if response: # <- you can be more precise here
    with open('out_file.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(response, f)
else:
    raise Exception # <- Your exception here
```

`pickle` is the defacto serializer in python, but, does have [issues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can pickle the response and save it. `pickle` is used for object serialization before storing it into disk.

```
import pickle

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != status.HTTP_200_OK:
    raise BadRequestError('message')

else: 
    with open('new.pkl','ab') as f: 
       pickle.dump(d,response)
```

`with open('new.pkl','ab') as f:` opens the file in append mode so that all the responses are appended to `new.pkl`. Otherwise, if opened in `'wb'` mode will overwrite the file each time you open it

Later to see the output you can do:

```
with open('new.pkl') as f:
      while 1:
        try:
            response= pickle.load(f)
            print response
        except EOFError:
            break
```

The reason to use the above code for unpickling is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761991/how-to-use-append-with-pickle-in-python)