# How to incrementally dump a dict to pickle?

Tags: python, dictionary, append, pickle, dump

I am trying to dump many dictionaries into the same pickle file. The dictionaries share the root key.

```
import pickle

a = {'k':'b'}
b = {'k':'c'}

f = open('tmp.pickle','ab')
pickle.dump(a,f)
pickle.dump(b,f)
f.close()

pickle.load(open('tmp.pickle','rb'))
```

Result:

```
{'k': 'b'}
```

I would expect:

```
{'k':{'a','b'}}
```

Comment: check out this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761991/how-to-use-append-with-pickle-in-python

Comment: @Roni in that question the dictionaries have a different root key

Comment: Your code is dumping two **separate** dictionaries into the pickle file, so it does not seem reasonable to expect to get a single merged version of them back when you later read the file. Also what should happen to keys & associated values they don't have in common?