# Can you use pickle in Append mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Consider the following example

```
import pickle
 l1 = [1,2,3,4]
 l2 = [5,6,7,8]
 with open("test.txt", "ab") as fp:   #Pickling
   pickle.dump(l1, fp)
 fp.close()

 with open("test.txt", "ab") as fp:   #Pickling
   pickle.dump(l2, fp)
 fp.close()

 with open("test.txt", "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
   b = pickle.load(fp)
```

What would be the output or the value of b?

Comment: After  45s of search: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761991/how-to-use-append-with-pickle-in-python/12762056#12762056

Comment: You could run the code and see what is the output of b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the following code:

```
import pickle
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
with open("test.txt", "ab") as fp:   #Pickling
   pickle.dump(l1, fp)
fp.close()

with open("test.txt", "ab") as fp:   #Pickling
   pickle.dump(l2, fp)
fp.close()

with open("test.txt", "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
   b = pickle.load(fp)
print(b)
```

And got the output `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. So, I guess the answer is yes.